# Methods not appearing when printing contract but do appear on Etherscan

Tags: web3js, contract-development, contract-deployment, javascript, etherscan

I have a goerli testnet contract [you can check out here](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x03e1daacf327d17294cbd917242f50e924a2cb40).  I'm trying to call `executeFlashLoan` using a javascript function using web3js, but the code acts as if the function doesn't exist.  However, it's clearly visible on the etherscan page.  Why am I not able to use it?  Details below.

Here's how it's called in the javascript:

```
const tradeData = await arbitrage.methods.executeFlashLoan(tradeInstructions).encodeABI();
```

The contract is verified and published on goerli if you want to look over the whole thing, but the pertinent part is here:

```
...

contract ArbitrageFlashLoan {

   ...

   function executeFlashLoan(TradeInstruction[] memory _tradeInstructions) external {
                
        // Step 1: Initiate flash loan
        require(_tradeInstructions.length > 0, "No trade instructions added");

        address[] memory assets = new address[](_tradeInstructions.length);
        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](_tradeInstructions.length);
        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](_tradeInstructions.length);

        assets[0] = _tradeInstructions[0].inputToken;
        amounts[0] = _tradeInstructions[0].amountIn;
        modes[0] = 0; // 0 for no debt swap, 1 for debt swap

        lendingPool.flashLoan(
            address(this),
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            address(this),  // Use the same address for onBehalfOf
            abi.encodeWithSignature("executeTrades(TradeInstruction[] memory)", _tradeInstructions),
            0
        );
    }
   
   ...

}

...
```

This always results in the error as so when called via the js function:

```
TypeError: arbitrage.methods.executeFlashLoan is not a function
    at executeTrades (/Users/Me/triBot/dfsBot.js:1088:51)
    at Subscription.callback (/Users/Me/triBot/dfsBot.js:140:21)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

When I deployed the contract, I printed it back and the methods section looked like this (shortened but you'll see what's important):

```
methods: {
    AAVE_LENDING_POOL_ADDRESS: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    '0x878a0135': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    'AAVE_LENDING_POOL_ADDRESS()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    executeFlashLoan: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    '0xe7bbc595': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    'executeFlashLoan((address,address,bool,uint256,uint256)[])': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    executeTrades: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    '0x07ed26d5': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    'executeTrades((address,address,bool,uint256,uint256)[])': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    fee: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    '0xddca3f43': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    'fee()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    lendingPool: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    '0xa59a9973': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
    'lendingPool()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],

   ... etc.
```

However, when I now print methods it looks like this:

```
{
  WETH: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0xad5c4648': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'WETH()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  currencies: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x6036cba3': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'currencies(address)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  owner: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x8da5cb5b': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'owner()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  sRouter: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x017c64b0': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'sRouter()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  tokenToMarketId: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0xb8268788': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'tokenToMarketId(address)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  uRouter: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x5cf39049': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'uRouter()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  executeTrade: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x1395dd23': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'executeTrade(bool,address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  callFunction: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x8b418713': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'callFunction(address,(address,uint256),bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject]
}
```

This is obviously not the same as what I published.  However, when you look at Etherscan, all my events and methods are there.  Why is this happening?  Is the contract just too new and it needs more time?

Comment: Are you configuring the arbitrage object correctly? Are you importing in that object the correct ABI from your smart contract? It seems just a problem with the ABI you import in the arbritage object. That object seems to refer to an arbitrage bot contract, like arb-bot or similar, not to your deployed contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems just a problem with the ABI you import in the `arbritage` object. That object seems to refer to an arbitrage bot contract, like [arb-bot](https://github.com/dennohpeter/arb-bot/blob/6ab8e25086d546b5c930bb7fff802f8fb91ed2bd/contracts/Arbitrage.sol) or similar, not to your deployed contract.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the answer.  I was pointing to an old version of the ABI.